# Opsworks cookbooks complains of missing method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I am trying to deploy my rails app with opsworks recipes that I get from AWS. I tried to setup the entire thing by referring a blog [here](http://pixelcog.com/blog/2014/virtualizing-aws-opsworks-with-vagrant/). Whatever he says is "php" or "php-app", I replaced with "rails" and my app name. 
My role JSON for the app looks like this -

`{
  "name": "hercules",
  "description": "OpsWorks recipe run-list for the rails app layer",
  "app_type": "rails",
  "default_attributes": {
    "max_pool_size": 5
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[opsworks_initial_setup]",
    "recipe[dependencies]",
    "recipe[unicorn::rails]",
    "recipe[rails::configure]",
    "recipe[deploy::default]",
    "recipe[deploy::rails]"
  ],
  "chef_type": "role",
  "json_class": "Chef::Role"
}`

When I try to deploy, it runs other recipes well and gets stuck on this error for `deploy::rails` -

`` ==> app: ================================================================================
==> app: Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/deploy/recipes/rails.rb
==> app: ================================================================================
==> app:
==> app:
==> app: NoMethodError
==> app: -------------
==> app: No resource or method named opsworks_deploy' forChef::Recipe "rails"'
==> app:
==> app:
==> app: Cookbook Trace:
==> app: ---------------
==> app:   /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/deploy/recipes/rails.rb:20:in block in from_file'
==> app:   /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/deploy/recipes/rails.rb:2:ineach'
==> app:   /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/deploy/recipes/rails.rb:2:in `from_file'
==> app: ``

If I open the `rails.rb:20`, that function is there - 

  `opsworks_deploy do
    Chef::Log.info("****** hi there *")
    Chef::Log.info("#{application}")
    Chef::Log.info(deploy.inspect)
    app application
    deploy_data deploy
  end`

Am I missing something terribly stupid here?

Comment: What does that line look like? Also worth noting that most Opsworks cookbooks won't run outside of Opsworks as they expect data to be filled in by AWS.

Comment: @coderanger, which line do you ask? That file `rails.rb` has the line and function definition there. Updated OP to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

OK. After spending 2 days behind this, in some far corner of google's search results, I found this - https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5011

Pasting some relevant info below -

> A change to the Recipe DSL causes any NoMethodError or NameError that occurs inside a Resource's do..end block to be incorrectly reported as something like
>   No resource or method named `file' for`Chef::Recipe "default"'
>   For example, the error in the following recipe code is clearly the `no_method_here` bit inside the file resource:
>   `file "/tmp/whatever" do
>     no_method_here
>   end`
>
> However, the error gets reported as:
>
> ================================================================================
>
> Recipe Compile Error in /private/tmp/error_message_repro/repro/recipes/default.rb
>
> ================================================================================
>
> NoMethodError
>
> ---
>
> No resource or method named `file' for`Chef::Recipe "default"'
>
> Cookbook Trace:
>
> ---
>
> `/private/tmp/error_message_repro/repro/recipes/default.rb:1:in`from_file'`
>
> Relevant File Content:
>
> ---
>
> `/private/tmp/error_message_repro/repro/recipes/default.rb:`
>
> 1>> file "/tmp/whatever" do
>     2:    no_method_here
>     3:  end
>     4:

And someone puts in a patch and a oneliner -

> `sudo wget https://github.com/opscode/chef/raw/29e732d97ec7e28b2111aca9f93edfd1bc257c2d/lib/chef/dsl/recipe.rb -O /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.0/lib/chef/dsl/recipe.rb --no-check-certificate`

(assumes your chef client is in /opt/chef)

Hope this helps someone going through same pain.